# How to set sprite as a background image?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am trying to use a sprite as a background, but the image does not cover entire camera area.

Currently, It looks like this (covering only a part) :
[image]

This is how i load image in `OnCreateResources` :

```
        backgroundTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),800, 480, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    mBackgroundTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(backgroundTextureAtlas,this.getAssets(),"background.png",0,0);
    backgroundTextureAtlas.load();
```

In `OnCreateScene`, creating a Sprite as :

```
    mBackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

How to scale image to fill entire area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an overloaded constructor for Sprite where you can specify height and width - make these the same height and width as your camera,

```
mBackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0.0f, 0.0f, mCamera.getWidth(),mCamera.getHeight(), mBackgroundTextureRegion);
```

Hope this helps.